# Cant update pip

Tags: python, pip

By doing `pip install --upgrade pip` I get the following:

```
Collecting pip
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/79/8a850fe3496446ff0d584327ae44e7500daf6764ca1a382d2d02789accf7/pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.1
    Uninstalling pip-18.1:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.1.dist-info/INSTALLER'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.3.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `--user` option or checking the permissions of that folder?

Comment: why are you messing with the system Python on the Mac? You should be using another Python installation and just leave that one alone

Comment: Use `pip3` instead.

Comment: `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.1.dist-info/INSTALLER'`
**`Consider using the '--user' option or check the permissions.`** is self explanatory.

Comment: To echo some of the comments above: don't work with the system files (i.e., don't upgrade the system pip; let Apple handle that, though they likely won't), and install a more recent Python 3 version and work with that. Pip also has not supported Python 2.7 since January 2021.

Comment: Try with `sudo` before the installation command.. it works sometimes

Comment: @enthusiast Better not in this case, for the reasons mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: I could update pip by using sudo in front but when I make use of pip I get the following:

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this (and similar errors in virtual environment) for a few hours when trying to install Django. Examples of my problems:

***Error 1:**
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3.packages.six.moves'*

***Error 2:**
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?*

Finally, I managed to solve these problems by deactivating the environment, deleting it and then creating a new, consistent env (relevant for Windows but adjust for your OS).

**Step 1:** Deactivate and delete venv or env

```
(env) > deactivate
> rmdir env (then choose option [A] Delete - Yes for all)
```

**Step 2:** Create a new virtual environment

```
> python -m venv env
```

**Step 3:** Activate newly created virtual environment

```
> .\env\Scripts\activate
```

**Step 4:** Upgrade pip and install Django

```
(env) > python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
(env) > python -m pip install django
```

**Step 5:** Verify correct Django Installation

```
(env) > python -m pip show django
```

Good luck!